# determining the best model for forecasting

Tags: r

I am trying to forecast some time series data, and I have usedpes of  three different types of model to forecast. Now I have noted down the performance of the models for each of the series which is noted by an unique id. The data format is like this:

```
ID MAPE_Model_Residual MAPE_Validation_Residual Diff_Residual
1    8355_0_32167            83.26487                 77.86192    5.40295030
2    8355_0_32168            93.44941                 93.51703    0.06761914
3    8355_0_32169            93.46655                 93.52344    0.05688714
4 8355_3936_32170            88.94154                 84.96923    3.97231385
5 8355_3937_32170            74.37984                 83.19228    8.81243847
6 8355_3940_32170            74.06081                 52.38760   21.67321223

  MAPE_Model_Fitted MAPE_Validation_Fitted Diff_Fitted MAPE_Model_Arima MAPE_Validation_Arima
          81.87216               74.91174  6.96041639         83.96876              80.19690
          93.36049               93.33518  0.02530898         92.93121              90.73525
         93.37859               93.33369  0.04489972         92.91448              90.74218
         88.24597               85.42486  2.82111289         88.69834              83.08940
          74.43546               83.19509  8.75962941         73.69333              74.74214
6          73.77239               52.97098 20.80140874         75.56103              63.57248

  Diff_Arima
   3.771864
   2.195963
   2.172300
   5.608939
   1.048811
  11.988552
```

there are three models each model accuracy, cross-validation accuracy and difference of them. I want to determine a model corresponding to a unique id which has the accuracies highest and difference lowest. Like a small example is

```
Model1                Model2           Model3

M1_2 M1_diff M2_1 M2_2 M2_diff M3_1 M3_2 M3_diff

A 55.2 60.8  5.6    66.7  69.8  3.1     58.5 60.3  1.8

B 56.8 55.4  1.4    62.8  63.9  1.1   65.7 69.8  4.1

C 52.3 54.3  2.0    53.8  55.9  1.1   56.7 57.9  1.2
```

I have to find which of the models 1,2,3 is best for each of A,B,C. the criteria are 
Mi_1 and Mi_2 shall be highest and Mi_diff shall be lowest. Like for id B it may be the second model. I cannot come up with any general algorithm to do this. The data is quite big has almost 1000 unique ids and cannot be one manually.I was thinking there may be some easy solution I am not getting. Can anyone please help? I am using R for my computations.

Comment: Yeah it deals with statistics, but the problem is not statistical. It is related to coding only, please read my example.

Comment: Why did you select id B for the second model? While it has the lowest M2_diff value, id A has a higher accuracy.

Comment: No, I have to select a model for an id, not id for a model. B has lowest diff for model 2, so I chose model 2 for B, model 3 could have been chosen too with its larger accuracy, but diff is big.

Comment: No this question don't deal with statistics. But I think you don't show any effort to resolve the problem. I mean there is no algorithm or code or at least an expected result, to say that we deal with a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a score function that combine the three values in one, and then you select the model that maximize the score (by id). Since all your values are positive, as a score function I will take this one:

```
 score = product(acc_1,acc_2)/diff
```

here how I will proceed:

First I reshape the data , in the long format (easier to proceed by (id ,model )):

```
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)
melted  <- melt(dat)
melted$model <- sub('_.*','',melted$variable)
head(melted)
# id variable value model
# 1  A     M1_1  55.2    M1
# 2  B     M1_1  56.8    M1
# 3  C     M1_1  52.3    M1
# 4  A     M1_2  60.8    M1
# 5  B     M1_2  55.4    M1
# 6  C     M1_2  54.3    M1
```

Then for each (id,model), I compute the score :

```
ddply(melted,.(id,model),summarise,
      score = prod(value[!grepl('diff',variable)])/ value[grepl('diff',variable)])


# id model     score
# 1  A    M1  599.3143
# 2  A    M2 1501.8258
# 3  A    M3 1959.7500
# 4  B    M1 2247.6571
# 5  B    M2 3648.1091
# 6  B    M3 1118.5024
# 7  C    M1 1419.9450
# 8  C    M2 2734.0182
# 9  C    M3 2735.7750
```

Finally for each id , I select the model that maximise the score:

```
ddply(scored,.(id),summarise,model = model[which.max(score)])

#   id model
# 1  A    M3
# 2  B    M2
# 3  C    M3
```

Comment: thanks a ton man:)... actually I am a statistics guy, not that good with coding. Can you suggest me some tutorials??

Comment: @user3702157 there is a lot of reference in the net, even here in SO FAQ. But try to get the basics. There is a certain learning curve, but R is wonderful specially to do statistics.

Comment: yes R has almost everything for all kinds of statistical computings